# Swift how to programmatically create and add a custom UIView

Tags: uiview, swift3

I have a custom UIView which compiles fine but crashes to AppDelegate with no error message. Here is my complete application code. I'm using Xcode Version 8.3 (8E162).

View

```
import UIKit

class TestView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Controller

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let testView: UIView = TestView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 50, height: 50))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        testView.backgroundColor = .green

        view.addSubview(testView)

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try this in the viewdidload :
    let testView: UIView = TestView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 50, height: 50))

Comment: The real version will require me to set various properties from a calling function that won't work for me. but I did try it and got the same crash

Comment: your code looking good .. and i tested it is working .. share your full relevant code or find out where is the problem arise

Comment: That is all of my code